# multiple feeds into one feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, xml-parsing

Is there a way to put multiple xml feed into one xml feed and order it by date of publish?

The xml feed is from different websites and I want to create another xml to put all the contents of each xml feed.

The problem is the loading time to parse all the xml feeds. I got 8 website feeds to parse.
Another problem is how do I arrange them by publishing date.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a temporary array and get all the feeds in it. Then sort the array by date and display. To get the items from one feed you can use magpierss to loop through all the items.

Below is an example of how to use magpie rss. Reference: http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/

```
require_once 'rss_fetch.inc';

$url = 'http://magpie.sf.net/samples/imc.1-0.rdf';
$rss = fetch_rss($url);


    $tempArray = array();
foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
    $tempArray[]['title'] = $item['title'];
    $tempArray[]['url']   = $item['link'];
    $tempArray[]['date'] = $item['pubDate'];

    }
```

In the above example $tempArray will have all items of one feed. Similarly you need to get other items of other feeds into it. And then use uasort to sort by date.

Comment: I will try to use magpierss. but can it get any xml formats? because this 8 website has different xml formats.

Comment: Yes, it supports all types of feeds.

Comment: I have used magpie rss in few projects (twitter project, facebook feeds, news feeds...to name a few) and have never faced any kind of trouble so far.

Comment: Kindly upvote or tick if my answer/suggestion helps. (Just a request)

Comment: Thanks for the help. but some lines in magpierss script is depricated. Your answer is appreciated anyway. Thanks.